# Using ansible to add users' public keys to one user's authorized_keys file

Tags: configuration, configuration-management, ansible

Trying to add two people's Github public keys to a user's authorized users file. I am able to successfully retrieve the SSH keys:

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  vars:
    my_users:
      belminf: "belminf"
      bob: "tmessins"
  tasks:
    - name: Retrieving all keys from GitHub
      shell: /usr/bin/curl https://github.com/{{ item.value }}.keys 2> /dev/null
      register: ssh_keys
      with_dict: my_users

    - debug: var=ssh_keys
```

However, I'm unsure how to loop through `ssh_keys` results and use `authorized_keys` task to add the retrieved keys.

My ridiculous attempt:

```
   - name: Adding keys to authorized_keys
      authorized_key: user=belminf key="{{ item }}" path=/home/belminf/test_auth state=present
      with_items: ssh_keys.results
```

Results in `invalid key specified`. Understandably but I'm out of ideas. Anyone?

Comment: `Tried this but it fails:` --> what's error message did you get? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Added error message. Thanks. Seemed like such a horrible attempt I didn't want to go into it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I made some tweak on your playbook, and here is the revised version

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  vars:
    my_users:
      belminf: "belminf"
      bob: "tmessins"
  tasks:
    - name: Retrieving all keys from GitHub
      shell: /usr/bin/curl https://github.com/{{ item.value }}.keys 2> /dev/null
      register: ssh_keys
      with_dict: my_users

   - name: Adding keys to authorized_keys
      authorized_key: user=belminf key="{{ item.stdout }}" path=/home/belminf/test_auth state=present
      with_items: ssh_keys.results
      ignore_errors: yes
```

Some changes note:

- On `authorized_key` module, the key was changed to `item.stdout`. The stdout was public key that you need.
- On `authorized_key` module, I defined `ignore_errors: yes` to resume playbook execution whenever the your curl task failed to fetch, either internet problem or 404 Not found (like tmessins's key). Of course you can tweak it by [controlling what defines failure](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_error_handling.html#controlling-what-defines-failure) so it still failed when other error happened.

Comment: Works! I was trying to loop through the output of the command line-by-line assuming `authorized_key` only accepted one key as a parameter but apparently doesn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

As of Ansible 1.9, the value for `key` can be a url, obviating the need for curling the url via the `shell` module.

Example:

```
- name: Add my SSH key
  authorized_key: user=jeffwidman key=https://github.com/jeffwidman.keys
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple now:

```
- name: get github key(s) and update the authorized_keys file
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ username }}"
    key: "https://github.com/{{ username }}.keys"
```

for detail, check this github [role](https://github.com/arbabnazar/ansible-roles/blob/master/users-with-github-key/tasks/main.yml)

Comment: I don't see how your answer is any different from @jeff widman's answer.

Comment: I didn't only show the relevant part but also give the link to full role for reference